# Mostrar información de perfil después de hacer LogIn en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, login, auth

Estoy trabajando en un login y ya logré verificar el token. Pero tengo un problema para mostrar la información de perfil o del usuario despues de que inicia sesión.

**Asi estoy verificando el token:**

```
export const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];

    if (!token) return res.status(403).json({message: "No token provided"})

    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET)
    req.userId = decoded.id;

    const user = await User.findById(req.userId, {password: 0})
    if(!user) return res.status(404).json({message: "No user found"})

    next();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({message: 'Unauthorized'})
    }
};
```

**Este es mi login:**

```
export const logIn = async (req, res) => {
    
    const userFound = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email}).populate("roles");
    
    if (!userFound) return res.status(400).json({message: "User not found"})

    const matchPassword = await User.comparePassword(req.body.password, userFound.password)

    if (!matchPassword) return res.status(401).json({token: null, message: "Invalid password"})

    console.log(userFound)

    const token = jwt.sign({id: userFound._id}, config.SECRET, {
        expiresIn: 86400
    })

    return res.json({
        message: "Auth Succesful",
        token : token
    })
}
```

Con el **console.log(userFound)** si puedo ver la iformación del usuario logeado pero al incluir en el **res.json** el name, username, role del usuario no me los trae. Gracias

Comment: ¿Dices que si pones: `res.json({..., user: userFound});` no te envía a la vista?

Comment: Coloque de esta forma:

return res.json({ name: name, username: username, 
        message: "Auth Succesful",
        token : token
    })

Comment: ¿Y las variables `name` y `username` están definidas? En todo caso debería ser: `res.json({name: userFound.name, username: userFound.username, ... });`. De lo contrario al ser `undefined` no se enviarán al cliente.